# Почему не удается написать текст поверх bitmap для маркера google map  API V2?

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь написать текст на маркере для карты, для этого я хочу взять чистый bitmap и нанести на него текст.  Но bitmap возвращается чистым, каким он есть, ни следа текста.
**PS:** `scale >=1;`

```
           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(56.83789, 60.5986))                              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawTextToBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_maps_marker,"19"))));

//тут пытаюсь нанести текст на bitmap
         public static Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext,int gResId,String gText) {
                Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
                float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
                Bitmap bitmap =
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);

                android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
                        bitmap.getConfig();
                if(bitmapConfig == null) {
                    bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                }
                bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));
                paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

                Rect bounds = new Rect();
                paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
                int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2;
                int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2;

                canvas.drawText(gText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);

                return bitmap;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнавать плотность экрана **scale** необходимо было только для того, чтобы определить размер текста. Чтобы нарисовать текст на **Canvas** не нужно использовать **scale**, так как смещение **x** и **y** уже подсчитаны для конкретного **bitmap**.
Попробуйте так:

```
canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);
```

Это работает на четырех устройствах.

[image: img1]
[image: img2] 
[image: img2] 
[image: img3]

Comment: да, только как на счет андроида 4.2.2?

Comment: Прекрасно работает у меня в эмуляторе(Android 4.2.2):  http://s42.radikal.ru/i095/1303/99/3fcf8eaf4ae3.jpg

Comment: вот а у меня девайся с 4.2.2 :) проблема в этом

Comment: Samsung Galaxy s3

Comment: А получившиеся x и y не выходят за размеры bitmap?

Comment: нет :) в том то и дело, я сначала сам пытался разбираться, все было отдебажено на несколько раз

Comment: Могу посоветовать отписаться на форуме о galaxy s3(например 4pda), дать им apk-шник. Кто-нибудь запустит и отпишется, есть ли такая проблема.